# Using Careful Spell on a wild magic fireball

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, wild-magic, metamagic

If a sorcerer wild mage rolls on the wild magic table and ends up casting a [fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball) centered on themself, can the mage use Careful Spell when they cast that fireball, allowing the mage and some of their party members to succeed on their saving throws against the spell and take half damage?

Answer (score 27):

The newly released [errata](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) for the PHB answers this question definitively:

> If a Wild
>   Magic effect is a spell, it’s too wild to be
>   affected by Metamagic. If it normally requires concentration, it doesn’t require
>   concentration in this case; the spell lasts
>   for its full duration.

So you can't use any form of metamagic on spells cast by your Wild Magic.

Comment: just came here to post this :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

The wording on meta magic is "when you cast" and the wording on the wild mage table is "you cast." Since you are casting a spell, and have access to meta magic, you can definitely us meta magic such as careful spell on the spells you cast via the wild magic table.

Additionally, there is nothing in the Wild Magic sorcerer writeup that indicates that meta magic cannot be used.

Comment: Normally I would rule no....as is the intended nature of Wild Magic, to be untamed acts of random magic.  As you point out, however, the Wild Magic description nor the Meta Magic description counters this.  Wild Magic says 'cast' . Meta Magic says it can be used on any spell you cast.  Tricky.  I think the goal was for a random unchecked or altered fireball to the face however.  My Tiefling Sorcerer will be rejoiced to hear this news!

Comment: Can you use metamagic on spells cast from an item that says "you can cast..."?

Comment: @PurpleVermont I'd say yes.

Comment: @waxeagle I think that may differ depending on the type of item.  I would rule yes for items that use the caster's own casting stats, and no for items that use another caster's stats.  (In the latter case, we envision the spell as being "fully formed" in the item, and not subject to metamagic or sculpting on the way out.)

Comment: This answer was invalidated by the 2015 PHB errata, as mentioned in the other answer.